# SQL parameter table

Tags: t-sql, parameters, mapping

I suspect this question is already well-answered but perhaps due to limited SQL vocabulary I have not managed to find what I need. I have a database with many code:description mappings in a single 'parameter' table. I would like to define a query or procedure to return the descriptions for all (or an arbitrary list of) coded values in a given 'content' table with their descriptions from the parameter table. I don't want to alter the original data, I just want to display friendly results.

1. Is there a standard way to do this?
2. Can it be accomplished with SELECT or are other statements required?

Here is a sample query for a single coded field:

```
SELECT TOP (5)
    newid() as id,
    B.BRIDGE_STATUS, 
    P.SHORTDESC      
FROM
    BRIDGE B
    LEFT JOIN PARAMTRS P ON P.TABLE_NAME = 'BRIDGE'
    AND P.FIELD_NAME = 'BRIDGE_STATUS'
    AND P.PARMVALUE = B.BRIDGE_STATUS
ORDER BY
    id
```

I want to produce 'decoded' results like:

```
| id                                   | BRIDGE_STATUS |
|--------------------------------------|------------   |
| BABCEC1E-5FE2-46FA-9763-000131F2F688 |  Active       |
| 758F5201-4742-43C6-8550-000571875265 |  Active       |
| 5E51634C-4DD9-4B0A-BBF5-00087DF71C8B |  Active       |
| 0A4EA521-DE70-4D04-93B8-000CD12B7F55 |  Inactive     |
| 815C6C66-8995-4893-9A1B-000F00F839A4 |  Proposed     |
```

Rather than original, coded data like:

```
| id                                   | BRIDGE_STATUS |
|--------------------------------------|---------------|
| F50214D7-F726-4996-9C0C-00021BD681A4 | 3             |
| 4F173E40-54DC-495E-9B84-000B446F09C3 | 3             |
| F9C216CD-0453-434B-AFA0-000C39EFA0FB | 3             |
| 5D09554E-201D-4208-A786-000C537759A1 | 1             |
| F0BDB9A4-E796-4786-8781-000FC60E200C | 4             |
```

but for an arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: The `postgressql` and `tsql` tags are, as a rule, incompatible (as shown in their descriptions). Do you need a solution that works for both? Based on your sample data I _think_ you're asking how to generate a column containing a column-delimited list of values, e.g. "Active, Leather, Shoehorn". That is often done in TSQL using `stuff` and `xml`.

Comment: Removed `postgressql` tag and updated post for clarity.